# A quick question about culling

Tags: xna, culling, face

So I have some vertices that I'm drawing with XNA and the issue I had ages ago was that they weren't appearing when the camera was placed above them. By turning on backface culling this fixed it, but now I'm also using 3D models and whenever backface culling is turned on it goes through it. I could just turn it on and off based on when these objects get drawn, but that feels like such a sloppy fix and I remember the person who helped me mentioned something about the order that the vertices are drawn in is what determines the natural culling state for them. Could somebody please elaborate on this and explain how I could get the original vertices to be drawn properly with backface culling off?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to change the title of your question. "A quick question about culling" says very little about what you want to ask.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the order of the vertices of each triangle. The vertices can be saved clockwise or counterclockwise. The default what most 3D programs should do is counterclockwise. In XNA 4.0 you can set the cullmode like this:

```
GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise;
//GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullClockwise;
//GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullNone;
```